# How can I use data from another flow data in flow? (Kotlin Flow)

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I wrote the code as below.

```
suspend fun getDataByRegion(): Flow<Result?> {
    // getRegion() return Flow<Region>
    return getRegion().map { region: Region ->
        repository.requestDataFromServer(region)
    }
}
```

The problem is that repository.requestDataFromServer(region) called twice.

So I think I should use operators like `zip` or `combine`.

When using these operators, how can the second flow use the data of the first flow?

Comment: How do you know that data is emitted twice? Did you add log statements? Include them in the question.

Comment: In the existing code, I cannot find any problems. Can you post more code?

Comment: Why is this function marked `suspend`? Seems like `getRegion()` simply returns a Flow, so it shouldn't be a suspend function either.

Answer (score 1):

With `combine` and `zip` operators you can not depend on the other's result. So in general your chaining approach with `map` is OK.

There is several options you have:

- Assuming your repository method is not called from anywhere else, the reason for it being called twice is that the region `Flow` is emitting twice. So try to find out why this is the case.

  Anyhow if your region `Flow` method returns the same region twice you can fix it by simply adding
  `.distinctUntilChanged()` after `getRegion()` like:

  ```
  getRegion().distinctUntilChanged().map { region: Region ->
     repository.requestDataFromServer(region)
  }
  ```

  It will make sure your region `Flow` doesn't emit redundantly with the same data. Alternatively add `distinctUntilChanged()` directly to the repository method, if this is always the expected behavior.
- Ask yourself if this method really needs to return a stream (`Flow`). I guess you need a stream since the region can change at runtime and you want something in your app to update automatically? But if not you could simply convert the stream to a single result:

  ```
  val region = getRegion().first()
  repository.requestDataFromServer(region)
  ```